# Paperclip refresh error "No such file or directory - /tmp/paperclip-reprocess"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I have a model with a paperclip image attachment and i'm adding a new style to the image and want to generate the new style for old photos.

I'm doing:

```
rake paperclip:refresh CLASS=Blog
```

and I'm getting the error

```
No such file or directory - /tmp/paperclip-reprocess
```

On the github page it says that's the command, I also found it on several question here on StackOverflow. I've also tried this commands:

```
rake paperclip:refresh:missing_styles CLASS=Blog
rake paperclip:refresh:missing_styles
```

with no results.

**EDIT**: Added the trace

```
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - /tmp/paperclip-reprocess20140416-25763-5k19nh
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@gemset/gems/paperclip-    2.4.2/lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:262:in `generate_fingerprint'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@gemset/gems/paperclip-2.4.2/lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:229:in `fingerprint'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@gemset/gems/paperclip-2.4.2/lib/paperclip/interpolations.rb:137:in `fingerprint'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@gemset/gems/paperclip-2.4.2/lib/paperclip/interpolations.rb:34:in `block (2 levels) in interpolate'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@gemset/gems/paperclip-2.4.2/lib/paperclip/interpolations.rb:33:in `gsub'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@gemset/gems/paperclip-2.4.2/lib/paperclip/interpolations.rb:33:in `block in interpolate'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@gemset/gems/paperclip-2.4.2/lib/paperclip/interpolations.rb:32:in `each'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@gemset/gems/paperclip-2.4.2/lib/paperclip/interpolations.rb:32:in `inject'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@gemset/gems/paperclip-2.4.2/lib/paperclip/interpolations.rb:32:in `interpolate'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@gemset/gems/paperclip-2.4.2/lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:408:in `interpolate'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@gemset/gems/paperclip-2.4.2/lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:168:in `path'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@gemset/gems/paperclip-2.4.2/lib/paperclip/storage/filesystem.rb:47:in `block in flush_writes'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@gemset/gems/paperclip-2.4.2/lib/paperclip/storage/filesystem.rb:37:in `each'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@gemset/gems/paperclip-2.4.2/lib/paperclip/storage/filesystem.rb:37:in `flush_writes'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@gemset/gems/paperclip-2.4.2/lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:190:in `save'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@gemset/gems/paperclip-2.4.2/lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:300:in `reprocess!'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@gemset/gems/paperclip-2.4.2/lib/tasks/paperclip.rake:35:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@gemset/gems/paperclip-2.4.2/lib/paperclip.rb:142:in `block in each_instance_with_attachment'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@gemset/gems/paperclip-2.4.2/lib/paperclip.rb:141:in `each'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@gemset/gems/paperclip-2.4.2/lib/paperclip.rb:141:in `each_instance_with_attachment'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@gemset/gems/paperclip-2.4.2/lib/tasks/paperclip.rake:34:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@gemset/gems/paperclip-2.4.2/lib/tasks/paperclip.rake:33:in `each'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@gemset/gems/paperclip-2.4.2/lib/tasks/paperclip.rake:33:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@gemset/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@gemset/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => paperclip:refresh => paperclip:refresh:thumbnails
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: Can you share the complete error stacktrace in the question?

Comment: @KirtiThorat I've added the stacktrace.